# HTML: calc(50vw - 1px) not setting proper width

Tags: html, css

(I am not able to make a code snippet as there is no button to do so visible. Will do one as soon at the option reveals itself)
Basically, I was working on adapting my site to mobile devices. However, the `calc(50vw - 1px)` in `section.defaultsection`'s css class doesn't seem to work for me, as for some reason the section is a bit wider (minor pixer difference).

```css
body{
    background: url('../RESOURCES/bgs/potential-bg2.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a:link{
    color: black;
}
a{
    color: black;
}

a section.allergyclmarker:hover, section.defaultsection:hover{
    box-shadow: 0vw 0vh 2vw burlywood;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
a section.wladislausclmarker:hover, section.defaultsection:hover{
    box-shadow: 0vw 0vh 2vw #FF5B00;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
section.defaultsection:hover{
    box-shadow: 0vw 0vh 2vw #04FFD4;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

section.defaultsection{
    position: relative;
    margin: 5% auto;
    width: calc(40vw - 1px);
    border: white 1px solid;
    border-radius: 20vh;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 3vw;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: 0vw 0vh 0.5vw grey;
}
main{
    margin-top: 10%;
}
section.textcontainer{
    font-family: Raleway;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}
section.textcontainer > h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2vw;
    margin-bottom: 0.8vw;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}
section.textcontainer > p{
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 3vw;
    font-size: 1vw;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
section.defaultsection *{
    display: inline-block;
}

img.iconimage{
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
}

header img{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12vw;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 20vh;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px white solid;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0vw 0vh 0.2vw grey;
}

footer{
    padding: 2vh 2vw;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 3vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer > p{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 1vw;
}
footer p a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 647px)
{
    section.defaultsection
    {
        display: initial;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        height: 70vh;
        width: calc(50vw - 1px);
        box-shadow: 0;
        border: 0;
    }
    footer
    {
        clear: both;
    }
    main
    {
        margin: 0;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Informacje o alergiach opracowane przez członków klasy .">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="keywords" content="ShatterOS, shatterwares, Shatterwares, ShatterWares, Shatteros, shatteros, historia 1a projekt, Władysław Łokietek, alergie, 1a ZSEk Opole biologia projekt, alergia pomoc, alergia co to, wstrząs anafilaktyczny">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/cssdata-corridor.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" href="RESOURCES/promise.png">
        <meta name="subject" content="Project hub">
        <meta name="author" content="Jakub">
        <meta name="language" content="pl">
        <meta name="owner" content="Jakub">
        <meta name="url" content="https://shatterwares.com">
        <meta name="coverage" content="Worldwide">
        <meta name="rating" content="General">
        <meta name='HandheldFriendly' content='True'>
        <title>Shatterwares Project Hub</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="RESOURCES/logo2.png">
        </header>

        <main>
            <a href="alergie/index.html" alt="Odnośnik do alergii">
                <section class="allergyclmarker defaultsection">
                    <img src="RESOURCES/wheatmini.png" class="iconimage" alt="zboże">
                    <section class="textcontainer">
                        <h1 style="font-size: 1.3vw;">Alergie: pewniaki</h1>
                        <p>"Alergie: pewniaki" to strona mająca na celu edukację jednostki w obrębie tematyki alergii oraz innych zagadnień będącymi koniecznymi elementami powyższego agregatu informacji.
                        
                        <b>Data ukończenia:</b> 4/5/2023</p>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </a>
            <a href="wladyslawlokietek/index.html">
                <section class="wladislausclmarker defaultsection">
                    <img src="RESOURCES/łokietomini.png" class="iconimage" alt="W.Łokietek">
                    <section class="textcontainer">
                        <h1 style="font-size: 1.3vw;">Łokietek: Wladislaus, Dei gracia, Rex Polonie</h1>
                        <p>"Łokietek: Wladislaus, Dei gracia, Rex Polonie", dzieło, to twoje najlepsze źródło wiedzy historycznej dot. Władysława Łokietka pod słońcem! Dokument zawiera dane, z którymi każdy porządny Polak powinien choć raz się zapoznać.
                        
                        <b>Data ukończenia:</b> W trakcie opracowywania</p>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </a>
            <section class="defaultsection" style="cursor: not-allowed;">
                <img src="RESOURCES/promise.png" class="iconimage" alt="ShWPH">
                <section class="textcontainer">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 1.3vw;">ShatterWares Project Hub</h1>
                    <p>ShatterWares Project Hub to intersekcja osiadła na stronie shatterwares.com służąca do szybkiej nawigacji wśród wielu projektów grupy. Dokument prowadzony jest przez , implementującego różnorakie oraz częste aktualizacje w stronie.
                    
                    <b>Ostatnia aktualizacja:</b> 5 maja 2023</p>
                </section>
</main>

        <footer>
            <p>This site is © <a href="https://github.com/jakubekgranie" target="_blank" alt="JN's GitHub"></a>. Projects are © by their authors. All rights reserved.</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

So far, I've tried:

- disabling borders,
- margins,
- element-bound paddings and margins
- disabling the `border-radius` property altogether
- changing the `display` property

**NOTE: The changes are visible when the media query is triggered (max-width: 647px)**

Comment: looks like it's `calc()` is working. what are you expecting here ?

Comment: @MadanBhandari i want the sections to be of size equal to 50% width of the screen, so each 2 elements can be next to each other

Comment: Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;`, as the padding is otherwise _added_ to the width of the box, not included in it. Setting `box-sizing` to this will include bordera and padding inside the `width`.

Comment: @somethinghere it did work out indeed! Hovever, it doesn't unless i turn the mobile preview on in inspect element (doesn't "float" the elements to the left in a resized window, the resolution is the same). Do you have any clue why? Should i bother?

Comment: Well, `box-sizing` should work in either mobile or desktop view. I personally would try to not use `float` at all since there's much better, more controllable ways to lay things out out there.

Comment: add `box-sizing: border-box;` as @somethinghere suggested and your are also missing one close `</section>` just before `</main>`. this will fix your problem.  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/wp18e06r/16/)

Comment: @somethinghere if i didnt bother you enough by now, can you, please, provide some examples?

Comment: Stuff like flexbox and grid are going to be much more predictable than floats, and solve that nasty issue of calculating all sizes minus a pixel just to not break over multiple lines. I can't really turn your example code into that here, I haven't the time to dissect all the choices made, but have a read on the two layout methods I mentioned.